# Is MinGW stable enough

Tags: c++, c, windows, gcc, mingw

Is `MinGW` (gcc port on Windows) stable enough for compiling a DLL consisting of various data algorithms (no DirectX, no graphics, ...) for 24/7 production?
We need to make a decision and from many reasons we do not want to use Visual C++.

So question is: "Is current MinGW stable enough for production?"

Comment: It was meant as "Would you compile a production app with MinGW?"

Comment: Moved my comment to an answer (along with addressing your actual question)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[It is several years old (13 years it seems)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MinGW), and actively maintained.  It has a branching strategy that has a stable branch and a development branch.  I'd call that stable enough for production :)

Licensing might be an issue for you, though.  If you don't pay anyone, you have no contractual support, and can't sue if there is a bug that causes you to lose money (check the license before you trust me on that, though).

The only problems I had with it were with documentation on autotools support, but I was new to autotools, that was 7 years ago, and I was trying to make a DLL that could be used as a drop-in replacement to a Visual Studio project.  YMMV.

Comment: There is no reliably way to emulate a MSVC C++ DLL yet, I fear. There are some issues (Structured Exceptions for example) that may prevent to get ABI compatible in C++. If a C interface works for you though, then it's okay.

Comment: @Matthieu: Good info.  The problem I had was ages ago, I didn't fully understand the problems (and was learning how DLL function exports even worked), and in the end I didn't actually have to support that. :)  But it might be useful to the OP.

Comment: _Structured_ Exceptions should work, as they are a Windows ABI feature. C++ exceptions, on the other hand, are not. In particular, it's not guaranteed that C++ exceptions are implemented on top of SEH.

Comment: @MSalters: I think there are some patent issues with Structured Exceptions preventing anyone else from using them, it's been discussed on the Clang mailing list when a GSOC candidate proposed to implement the Windows ABI but no conclusion could be reached (whether legal or not), so it was abandonned. If you *know* it's possible, then please do contact the Clang team, they'll be glad to know about it I think :)

Comment: @Matthieu: Well, you can't use them on non-Windows OS'es for those reasons (assuming the patent holds), but that's rather irrelevant to MinGW. That's just GCC for Windows, so it doesn't need to worry.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, MinGW is most definitely stable and reliable for production code.